# ASP.NET Core and ViewModelFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ioc-container

Hello, I'm trying to implement a ViewModelFactory "pattern" and I was wondering what's the best way to achieve it, considering the constraints of the current IoC container.

```cs
public class UserCreateViewModelFactory
{
     private readonly DbContext db;

     public UserCreateViewModelFactory(DbContext db){ this.db = db;}

     public void Create(CreateUserViewModel viewModel)
     {
          //Creates the user
     }
}
```

I have the above class easily injected into my controllers ctor. The head ache will come when I need more ViewModelBuilders, So I want to avoid two things:

1. Bloat ctor with injections
2. Bloat container with registrations

I want to be able to inject an `IViewModelFactory` on my controller and then using it like this:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetUsers(int id)
{
    return View(viewModelFactory.Build<GetUserViewModel>(id));
}
```

Notice that on calling `Build(T)` it has to call the correct `IViewModelFactory` implementation.

I know that StructureMap container support binding the concrete implementations to the corresponding interface but I'm trying to come up with a solution without having to add another dependecy to the project.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to abstract the creation of view models? A view model is a DTO; it's something that the Controller should typically new up itself. There's usually no reason to abstract away the creation of DTOs.

Comment: Imagine that you have complex view models. Allowing that creation code directly in the body of your controllers actions is just bad. Is the same principle of why you delegate services to do complex business code. 

I'm aiming for slim controllers here, so an action is supposed to do very little, like aswering to the users request and returning its results.

Comment: Your application might benefit from designs like [this one](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Comment: @steven I've recently read Jim Bogart's [Put your controllers on a diet](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/12/19/put-your-controllers-on-a-diet-posts-and-commands/) series of posts. And I've become very fond of the CQRS pattern. Although it's a great pattern, for now I'm separating my business logic through services. 

I'm having trouble to apply the same Mediator pattern to resolve factories implementations because of aspnet core IoC. I'm trying to reproduce something [this](http://benfoster.io/blog/using-the-view-factory-pattern-in-aspnet-mvc) without the service locator antipattern.

Comment: Prevent letting your container forcing limitations on your design. Desgn should be leading, your framrworks and libraries of choice should follow from the selected design, never the other way around.

Comment: This is definetely true. I'm just searching for ways to implement this whitout having to add more dependencies to the project. Maybe I'm missing a good implementation alternative and I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sometime researching, I finally came up with a good solution for the this problem.

The solution is basically extending the default IoC capabilities through an `IServiceCollection.ConnectImplementations()` extension method.

During registration I'll search my concrete classes and connect them with its respective interfaces (like other containers). Then I use a Mediator/Proxy that has `IServiceCollection` injected and knows which concrete class should be building the view model.

The full solution is better explained by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/thiagomajesk/bb493719674c57c6eec6975ca3fe7835) I've created.

Comment: How would this work if you need support for multiple input parameters to create the viewmodel?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you have builders for building viewmodels, then factory is extra layer of abstraction which simply can be dropped off.
Because you know the type of created viewmodel at compile time you can just inject a builder you need to the controller constructor.

If your controller create a lot of viewmodels and you end up with a lot of builders you need to inject - this can be considered as a sign of violation of Single Responsibility Principle. In that case you need to separate logic of controller to different controllers.

> So I want to avoid two things:
>
> Bloat ctor with injections

- Separate class with bloated constructor to another classes with more specific responsibility which takes smaller amount of dependencies.
- Or wrap dependencies with one or two, three classes based on their relation

> Bloat container with registrations

- This cannot be a problem, because dependency containers is usually designed to register whole "object graph" of your application

Comment: It's a matter of organization too - as controllers can use other dependencies.

And It's not necessarily a sing of violation of SRP, it depends interelly on the domain needs. A good example is the use of CQRS + Mediator.

This answer is not very helpful as it doesn't address the problems constraints (as specified).

Comment: Controller is just a class - if class have too many dependencies - which is main concern of your question - then it violate Single Responsibility Principle. A class need to have only one reason to change, so if your controller have different logic of creation different viewmodels - then if some of the logic need to change you need to change a controller code.

Comment: That's simply not true. The amount of parameters doesn't represent a violation of SRP. Altough it can indicate a code smell and possibly a violation of SRP because the code "might" be doing more than it's supposed to do.
 
Take for example a ProductController, it should be responsible for routing/returning views to the Product entity. Maybe I've a business requirement that allows me to edit/display a Product in different ways. In that case my "one reason to change" is to provide functionality relevant to my domain that is supposed to be in that controller.

Comment: If responsibility of Controller is _routing/returning views_, then responsibility for creating of viewmodels for _edit/display a Product in different ways_ will need to be extracted to another class(the reason why, I think, you have introduced a factory class). In this case your controller need only one dependency on factory class.

Comment: Now you've got it!
Do you realize that if I want to inject, for instance a single `IViewModelFactory` on my controller the application must know how to call the appropriate concrete type that implements the right `IViewModelFactory.Build(T)`?This is like mediator pattern. 
The default container is rather simplistic and doesn't know how to connect the concrete types, then I'm trying to extend the `IServiceCollection` to scan the assemblies and register the concrete types myself. If I succeed on that path I'll update the question. Meanwhile I'll appreciate any other contributions.